# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Tuple'?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, tuples

Here am implementing Tuple for using two models in my view. But am getting the following error :

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   `System.Tuple'2[WebApplication.Models.log_voyage,System.Collections.Generic.List'1[WebApplication.Models.log_ligne_voyage]]»`, but this dictionary requires a model item of type `«System.Tuple'2[System.Collections.Generic.List'1[WebApplication.Models.log_voyage],System.Collections.Generic.List'1[WebApplication.Models.log_ligne_voyage]]»`.

Here is my View:

```
@using WebApplication.Models;
@model Tuple<List<log_voyage>, List<log_ligne_voyage>>


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout1.cshtml";
}
```

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Index( int id = 0 )
 {

     var first =  entities.log_voyage.Where(v => v.Num_Voy == lastVoyageID).FirstOrDefault();
     log_voyage voyage1 = entities.log_voyage.Find(lastVoyageID);
     var second = entities.log_ligne_voyage.Where(x => x.NUM_Voy == lastVoyageID).ToList();
     var t = new Tuple<log_voyage, List<log_ligne_voyage>>(first, second);
     return View(t);

}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Tuple<log_voyage, List<log_ligne_voyage>> voy)
{
    try
    {
        if (voy.Item1.Dat_Voy == null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Dat_Voy", "Incorrect Date.");
        }
        //.............Some Code .........//

            entities.Entry(voy.Item1).State = EntityState.Modified;
            entities.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Miss_Voyage");
        }
        else
        {
            GetListcontoller();
            return View(voy);
        }
    }
    catch (DataException /* dex */)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Impossible d'executer cette action. contacter le service info SVP.");
        GetListcontoller();
        return View("Index", "Home");
    }
}
```

Any suggestion Please ?

Comment: Compare `Tuple<List<log_voyage>, List<log_ligne_voyage>>` from your view and what you're expecting in the Index method: `Tuple<log_voyage, List<log_ligne_voyage>>` Do you see the difference between those two pieces of code?

Comment: ahhh yes I change it but i had this error
Erreur du serveur dans l'application '/'.

Erreur de compilation
 CS1579: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'WebApplication.Models.log_voyage' because 'WebApplication.Models.log_voyage' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: Right, if you change it to just `Tuple<log_voyage, List<log_ligne_voyage>>`, you won't be able to iterate over the first part of the Tuple, since it's not a `List<T>` anymore.

Comment: so what i need to do !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mike McCaughan pointed out.

The model you are returning from controller is

```
Tuple<log_voyage, List<log_ligne_voyage>> voy
```

But the view is expecting

```
@model Tuple<List<log_voyage>, List<log_ligne_voyage>>
```

As you said getting error if you change view to

```
Tuple<log_voyage, List<log_ligne_voyage>>
```

try changing the controller to

```
Tuple<List<log_voyage>, List<log_ligne_voyage>>
```

Like the below code:

```
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Index(Tuple<List<log_voyage>, List<log_ligne_voyage>> voy)
   {
     try
     {
      if (voy.Item1.Count() == 0)
      {
          // followed by your code
```

Comment: then this  if (voy.Item1.Dat_Voy == null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Dat_Voy", "Incorrect Date.");
        }
dose not work any more

Comment: voy.Item1.FirstOrDefault().Date_Voy == null, hope this works ?

Comment: The same I changed to voy.Item1.Count() == 0 that means no elements present in that list which indirectly means Dat_Voy could be null.

Answer (score 0):

```
var first =  entities.log_voyage.Where(v => v.Num_Voy == lastVoyageID).FirstOrDefault();
```

will return a single instance of

```
 WebApplication.Models.log_voyage
```

Your view requires

```
 Tuple<List<log_voyage>, List<log_ligne_voyage>>
```

To get the List required for the first item in the Tuple, you will need to construct a list from the item you retrieve using "FirstOrDefault" or you'll need to change the model of the view.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a view model rather than a Tuple.

Your code would then look something like this:

```
public class VoyageViewModel
{
    public log_voyage log { get; set; }
    public List<log_ligne_voyage> log_ligne_voyage_list { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult Index(VoyageViewModel voyageViewModel)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: yes i did that befor tuple but i had a problem like this
i have a attribute in log_voyage  name Heure_Voy  i want to do this by using VoyageViewModel 
if (voyageViewModel.Heure_Voy == null ) do something but i can't call the Heure_Voy  that's the problem i didn't know how